# Passing object from Node/Express Router to AngularJS Controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have the following:

Node/Express router:

```
var City = require('./models/city');

    module.exports = function(app) {

        app.get('/cities/:zip', function(req, res) {
            console.log(req.params.zip);
             var query = City.find({"zip" : req.params.zip})
             query.exec(function(err, city) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);
                console.log(city);
                res.json(city);
            });
        });

        app.get('*', function(req, res) {
            res.sendfile('./public/views/index.html'); // load our public/index.html file
        });
    };
```

Angular Service:

```
angular.module('CityService', []).factory('City', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        get : function(zip) {
            var zip = zip.zip
            return $http.get('/cities/' + zip);
        }
     }       
}]);
```

Angular Controller:

```
angular.module('CityCtrl', []).controller('CityController', ['$scope', '$http', 'City', function($scope,  $http,  City){
$scope.update = function (zip) {
    $scope.weather = City.get({zip : zip});


    if(zip.length = 5){
        $http.jsonp('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip='+ zip +',us&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
        $scope.data=data;
        console.log(data.name);
        });
    }
}
}]);
```

Everything seems to be working fine.  However, when I try to log the $scope.weather I get the entire header.  I've tried logging $scope.weather.name (I know it's there) and then it returns "undefined".  When I check what the server is logging it appears to log the correct JSON response.  Any idea of how to get the "name" field of the returned document?

Comment: `City.get({zip : zip}).success(function(response){$scope.weather = response})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace    `$scope.weather = City.get({zip : zip});`  to `City.get({zip : zip}).then(function(response){$scope.weather= response.data});`

As we know $http return a promise object so you must have to resolve it. you are not resolving it in service so you have to set $scope.weather in `then`.

Comment: So if I do that and then I try to do console.log($scope.weather.city) or use {{weather.city}} in my view, I get undefined and I know the city is being returned in the object

Comment: angular.module('CityService', []).factory('City', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        get : function(zip) {
            var zip = zip.zip
            var defer = $q.defer();
           $http.get('/cities/' + zip).success(function(data){
               defer.resolve(data);
             })
             .error(function(err){
               defer.reject(err);
             });
             return defer.promise;
        }
     }       
}]);

Comment: replace your factory by this and use in controller the same way your were using.  $scope.weather = City.get({zip : zip});

Comment: same thing, trying to display {{weather.city}} return nothing.  console.log($scope.weather) returns d {$$state : Object}

Comment: With your original "City" implementation, if you use `City.get(...).then` the parameter is a response object so the you'd need to update the answer to `.then(function(response){$scope.weather = response.data})`. The `.success` function spreads the response object out so the first parameter is the data and why PSL's response above works.

Comment: @BradBarber if I try that and then I do console.log($scope.weather.city); I get undefined...

Comment: When are you doing `console.log($scope.weather.city)`? Make sure it's after the response has completed (inside `then`).

Comment: @yhussain  will you please print you weather object in your html view using json filter like {{weather | json }}, and let me what you get. is there city key on not ?

Comment: @BradBarber Doing so returns undefined. If i leave out the .city I get an object that I've taken a screenshot of: http://snag.gy/k2unn.jpg

Comment: @BharatBhushan this is what I get : [ { "_id": "5561204075e68f48dd422a5b", "id": "40553", "county": "Yolo", "state": "CA", "city": "Davis", "longitude": -121.749016, "latitude": 38.521776, "zip": "95616" } ]

Comment: Do you only have one weather entry per zip code? If so, you probably want to update your server-side implementation to return a single object instead of an array. If you can have multiple weather entries per zip, then use ng-repeat to go through each one.

Comment: yeah, i only do have one, i thought i was just sending one object (I do want all of the entries available like city, state, longitude) but i only have one city per zip code.

Comment: its seems your server is responding with array so you should use weather[0].city. or you have to change your response from server to send json object instead of array

Comment: One more thing find always return array instead of find you should use findOne().  that solve your whole problem

Comment: thanks for all your help, you guys have both clarified so many things i didn't understand

Comment: @yhussain great job!, happy to help you :)